# Django error in Heroku: "Please supply the ENGINE value"

Tags: python, django, heroku

I read and apply "Getting started with Django on Heroku" tutorial but ran into problem while syncing db:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured." 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.
```

I read [Please supply the ENGINE value Django database configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457441/please-supply-the-engine-value-django-database-configuration) and [“settings.DATABASES is improperly configured” error performing syncdb with django 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228618/settings-databases-is-improperly-configured-error-performing-syncdb-with-djang) but still receive same error. While executing

```
heroku run python manage.py --settings=moz455.settings syncdb
```

I receive error "Unknown command: '--settings=moz455.settings'".
How to solve this problem?

Version of Django is 1.4.

Comment: The issue is that although the "[Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django)" tutorial makes you install and use the "dj-database-url" package, it only mentions in passing that settings.DATABASES will be configured from the DATABASE_URL env variable. See [Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars); to use the database that Heroku sets up, see the [Using Foreman and heroku-config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-foreman-and-herokuconfig) paragraph (especially the `heroku config:pull` bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself: in manage.py add code similar to this:

```
CurDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
ProjectDir = os.path.join(CurDir, "moz455")
sys.path += [ProjectDir]
```

And commit changes with these commands:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "commit"
git push -f heroku
```

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same issue, but apparently for different reasons. In the Heroku docs at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#prerequisites, it says to add the following to `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

You can pass in a parameter of:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user:pass@localhost/dbname')
```

And that will allow you to develop locally and on Heroku. The part that actually SOLVES the problem I had though was that the Heroku config environment variable of DATABASE_URL was not actually set. To set this, I ran

```
$ heroku config
```

I saw the Database URL assigned to a separate config variable. So I created a new variable:

```
$ heroko config:add DATABASE_URL={#the database url}
```

That solved my problem. I hope it helps anyone else with similar issues.

Comment: Thanks mate, that saved my day. Was struggling with this from 2 hours.

Answer (score 8):

After trying all the answers here and verifying DATABASE_URL exists, nothing worked.

I added the second line and it worked

```
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config() <--- heroko docs says this is enough
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' <---- add this
```

Comment: This is all I had to do. I wonder if this is a necessary change for Django 1.5; I didn't have to do it previously. I also had to prefix both of these lines with `DATABASES = {}`

Comment: After I do this I get a new error: asking me to supply NAME.  It's as if dj_database_url.config() is not supplying the needful...

Comment: @GreenAsJade I had the same problem! Did you solve it?

Comment: @Constantine it was a while ago now, but best I can recall, I had confusion over what was reading what: there are so many ways of starting django up, and they seemed to have different effects.  I now how that line in my config, and start with foreman, and it works.   I have a comment that says "#if foreman is not reading the .env file
#DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default = 'postgres://user:@localhost/user')"  HTH

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you have the database add-on installed and setup properly.  See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#no-dev-database-or-no-database-url

I ran the following to fix the issue:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN
```

Comment: The `pg:promote` line might have a different color on the end - mine was `ORANGE`, I've seen `RED` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try different order:

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb --settings=moz455.settings
```

The manage.py command looks like this:

```
manage.py <command> <options>
```

but you used it like this:

```
manage.py <options> <command>
```

Your other problem (lack of ENGINE setting) may be caused by incorrect settings file being used during the syncdb command execution. The above should fix it also.

Comment: No, second (main) problem remains. Django doesn't see settings.py. On local computer I add this to manage.py: sys.path += ["D:/blizzard/Projects/Python/Web/moz455/moz455"], but what is the project dir on Heroku? And is it the right way?

Comment: @DSblizzard: Did you follow the guide from Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings)? They have [up-to-date guide for deploying Django apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django).

Answer (score 0):

it is a little late ; but you just delete all default django database settings lines ; and add heroku's one.

it will work correctly

** edit ** or simply you can use `socket.gethostname().

example :

```
if socket.gethostname() == 'xx':
    DATABASE_SETTINGS ={ }

elif socket.gethostname() == 'xxx':
    another database settings...
```

so you can run your project under multiple hosts.