# setting database: postgresql in django 1.8 in heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I have been struggling for this issue for the whole days while no solutions at all. so I post it here.

I am trying to set up a blog website in Heroku via Django 1.8 which uses Python 3.4.3. I follows the instructions from Heroku website [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django).

I use "foreman start" to run Django project in my Mac and I already installed all dependence.

Part of my setting.py file involving the database initially looks like:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Then I got error: ImproperlyConfigured at /settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.

Then I modify the files by adding one line supplying the ENGINE value:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826326/django-error-in-heroku-please-supply-the-engine-value) answered by Or Arbel, it should work. But I got another error: ImproperlyConfigured at /settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.

What should I do next? Actually my Django project is very simple and does not involve any database operations(may need in the future). I just want to make it works on Heroku. Thanks!

Do I need to create a database to continue? I just want to make the webpage works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your guys help, specially souldeux.

Update:

I have fixed the issue by using souldeux's method by providing more informations about the database. Here I want to emphasis that it seems the code from the original Heroku tutorial does not work for Django 1.8:

```
import dj_database_url   ####not working for my case
DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Initially I did not create a database because I think it is not necessary for simple projects, based on my understanding obtained from Heroku tutorial. Actually it does need to create a database in Heroku to make it works. The tutorial is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql). You need run "heroku config -s | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL" to get the database information. The format is like:

```
scheme://username:password@host:port/database
```

So you can get 'database', 'username', 'password', etc.

Afterwards, modify the 'settings.py' according to souldeux, then run following codes:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Ready to go to Heroku"
git push heroku master
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

Now it works. But other issues arise like my webpages do not show images... Anyway it solved. Please confirm my solutions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add more information to your database definition. For instance, here's what my own database entry looks like in my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'redacted',
        'PASSWORD': 'redacted',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

If you don't have a database user and password to enter in the fields marked **redacted** then you need to make sure you have the actual database created and psycopg2 installed.

Comment: Note that deploying Django own server is a different kettle of fish: you have to manage security updates, iptables, log rotation, deployment (none of Heroku's nice git push tricks), etc. It's a little misleading to make it sound easier.