# Confused with Django project directory

Tags: python, django, heroku

[Heroku's quick Django tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) recommends the following to start a new django project.

```
$ mkdir hellodjango && cd hellodjango
$ django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .
```

However, if I create a project as above, django seems to have a wrong reference for `settings.py` file. When you run `python manage.py syncdb`, and you get `Please supply the ENGINE value Django database configuration` error because django [cannot locate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228618/settings-databases-is-improperly-configured-error-performing-syncdb-with-djang) `settings.py` file correctly.

Is the above way of creating a project directory unconventional? Using `virtualenv` is kind of awkward without `.` when starting a project as it becomes:

```
~/project/venv
~/project/project/project/app
```

while the way suggested(adding `.` at the end) in Heroku's tutorial gives

```
~/project/venv
~/project/app
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to keep the virtual env directory out of the project itself, because you generally want the project folder to be in a revision control system like git.

You can tell Django which settings file to use with the `--settings=settingsmodule` argument to the `manage.py` command. You can also set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. You can also edit the `manage.py` file to change the default settings module. There should be a line in there that looks something like this:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
```

I don't really understand what you mean with the `.` at the end. You can enable your virtual environment by sourcing the virtual env's 'activate' script like so:

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

Then you can install your pip requirements and they'll end up in your virtual environment. Make sure to also run the `./manage.py runserver` command in the virtual environment.